# Is there a Rx Framework function which will create an observable which ends after a timespan has elapsed?

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

Some observables are just so *needy*. They want you to listen and listen and listen to all they have to say, maybe for all of time! What if I can really only handle a few seconds' of events? Could I write something like

```
mouseMoves.TakeFor(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
```

Conceptually, this would create a subject which would pass along events until a certain time had elapsed, then unsubscribe to the underlying observable and mark its own sequence complete. I suspect you could write it that way by hand, but it seems like there must be some existing operators which do this. I had hoped that `Observable.TimeOut` would do what I want, e.g. using

```
mouseMoves.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), Observable.Empty<T>())
```

But I think what it's doing is timing out the observable if the time span *between* observations is longer than the given value. This is useful, too, but not quite what I'm after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you need [`TakeUntil`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229530%28v=VS.103%29.aspx):

```
var source = Observable.FromEventPattern(...);

source.TakeUntil(Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
   .Subscribe(_ => {});
```

Comment: We must be using different versions of the framework? Observable.Timeout has no overloads which take just one argument. But presumably there is an observable factory which makes an observable that squawks just once after an elapsed time period. It's late and I should be in bed, but I shall look for such a thing in the morning.

Comment: Apologies, `Observable.Timer` was what I meant. `TakeUntil` is what you need; it reads from the source until a value from another sequence (Timer in this case) is emitted.